# Ionic2 - check if page is active

Tags: angular, ionic2

**How can I check if a ionic2 page is active?**

For example I want to hide a button if a page is active:

```
<button primary [hidden]="isActive('actualPageName')">
     Should be hidden
</button>
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly? The page should typically take up the entire view so any buttons on the page should be visible and any buttons on another page should not be visible

Comment: I want to pass the name of a page and check if I'm on this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IONIC 2 & 3:
Because of the uglification you cannot use pagename for production.

I check the active page by looking if the last page on the controller stack is of the instance of the page:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { myPage } from '../../pages/my/my';
...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
...
let active = this.navCtrl.last().instance instanceof MyPage;
```

IONIC 4:
Routing is changed. This looks like the new way:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(public router: Router) {}
...
let active =  this.router.isActive('mypage', false)
```

Comment: I'm curious and confused. How does checking the "if the last page on the controller stack is of the instance of page" give you the current active page?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @Rexford The Ionic stack is an array where you "push" and "pull" component, so the last Component in the stack is always is active one ;)

Comment: What about when we're using Ionic lazy loading pages? (loading pages by string names instead of typos) how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the active page and check its name:

```
public isActive(pageName: string): boolean {
   return this.navCtrl.getActive().name === pageName);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the comments you can see some users that claim this solution is not working for them due to the Uglify process. It sounds reasonable, but I still found the solution seems to work. I've compiled an APK with this code using this command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

During compilation you can see:

```
...
[13:00:41]  uglifyjs started ... 
[13:00:43]  sass finished in 2.45 s 
[13:00:43]  cleancss started ... 
[13:00:46]  cleancss finished in 3.05 s 
[13:00:57]  uglifyjs finished in 16.27 s
...
```

Then, when I run that app in the Android emulator I got the right page name using `this.navCtrl.getActive().name`.

I must say I've not tested it with a signed application in a real device.

May be Android or the emulator is not affected, may be the problem described by those users is solved in recent releases, may be I'm doing something wrong. Because I don't know the response to this questions I maintain my answer but I've added this info. Please, if you know more about this comment it instead of just ignoring or donwvoting this answer. If this answer is proven wrong I'll happily modify or delete it.

Comment: This is not a good solution. When you build a production version of your app it uglifies all the names and so your 'pageName' most likely will not work.

Comment: @Gauzy, are you sure the uglify process affects that name? I've searched for info but I can't find where it's explained. I could search more, but if you have a good link about this I would like to have a look.

Comment: I just experienced what @Gauzy said today, so I can confirm it is not working in production. Paul's answer is the right one.

Comment: @PeterPan666 what if I'm using Ionic lazy loading pages? (loading pages by string names instead of typos)

Comment: Sorry, I’ve never used lazy loading so I couldn’t tell :/

Answer (score 1):

Update to the @sanzante answers. You can retrieve an active page and check it's name as follows.

```
public isActive(pageName: string): boolean {
   return this.navCtrl.getActive().id === pageName);
}
```

It will work for the --prod build version as well.

ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#isActive

Read the doc above. Import `NavController` to your Page, then you can inject `NavController` into your Page using typescript:

```
constructor(public nav: NavController) {}
```

or using ES6:

```
constructor(nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
}
```

After all that, you can call `this.nav.getActive()` to see the current Page or call `this.nav.isActive('MyPage')` to check if you are on MyPage

Edit: the ES6 version isn't truly ES6 but should work for Ionic2

Comment: I'm missing something here.  nav.isActive() (per the docs you linked to in your answer) expects a param of type ViewController, so your example `this.nav.isActive('MyPage')` shouldn't work since you're sending it a string value.

Comment: Note: if you do String comparison use this.nav.getActive().name.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here are my 2 cents.

I believe a more cleaner solution would be to make use of the id property in the NavOptions, a draw back is that you need to pay attention to the id's you assign to avoid an id collision:

You instantiate the component like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(MyComponent, navParams, { id: 'my-component-1' });
```

Then you can simply check it like this:

```
this.navCtrl.getActive(true).id === 'my-component-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for different Pages component this.navCtrl.last().instance instanceof MyPage; should be sufficient if you want to compare between two pages instance of the same component the only option i found was use a ref to the container and next use the getBoundingClientRect function because the width of not visible pages is 0 this maybe can help to someone.

this.content.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width > 0

Answer (score 0):

I track it, a little less elegant but effective and simpler:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.isActualView=true;
}

ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.isActualView=false;
}

...

if(this.isActualView)...//here I know I am in the actual view or not
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for 2021 -- If you are using Angular for your Ionic project, this is how you can achieve the answer to the question:

```
<div routerLink="/tabs/tab1" [routerLinkActive]="'is-active'" #discover>
  <img [src]="discover.classList[0] == 'is-active' ? 'assets/tabs/explore-orange.png' : 'assets/tabs/explore-white.png'" />
  <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
</div>
```

`[routerLinkActive]="'is-active'"` will add the is-active class to that div when that route is active.